# grab 1/multiple cameras and encode?

Tags: video, encoding, video-capture, video-processing

I finally managed to grab a video from our Camera. There are several problems with that camera for grabbing fullHD under Windows and the only way is to use a tool that grabs the raw, huge file.

so i found the way under ubuntu:

```
dvgrab -format mpeg2 -buffer 300 - | ffmpeg -deinterlace -f mpegts -i - -f flv -vcodec flv -s 1920x1080 -aspect 16:9 -qscale 3.5 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 32k -ar 22050 Videoname.flv
```

This grabs my cam (Canon XHA1) and saves it as flv. works. is there a way to make a gui?

what i would like to make is a small tool/GUI with video preview, add second and third camera and for the last step, somehow manage to create a picture in picture encoding.

So, how could i do this or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I found your question on AskUbuntu. There are several issues with your approach and the result.

First of all you chose 22050 Hz as audio sampling rate which is not enough to capture audio properly (20 Hz to 20 kHz). According to Nyquist (see [Nyquist frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency)) you need to double that. This is why CDs use 44.1 kHz.

Then you are pulling interlaced material from the camera. There do exist filters like [TGMC](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/TempGaussMC) that can treat interlaced material really well but they use quite an amount of resources to achieve that. Also to set up Avisynth with all the plugins needed for that filter in Wine and have some sort of multithreading reliably working is quite a pain. (VapourSynth may have solved multithreading and stability.)

Long story short: There is no easy and fast way to get Bluray quality video from this camera, so I recommend you use the 720p output or probably buy an new camera that records in 1080p and provides output in proper format.

Comment: sad to hear that. for now i have to work with that cameras until we decide to buy new ones. We thought about it. Thank you for your answer. the properties i chose were just for testing :-)

Can you recommend some cameras for live capturing?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with cameras.